# Oracle 12c updating multiple rows with the same data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to write a script that pulls out all of the distinct 'words' in a string and saves them in another field. I've gotten the process to work in Oracle 19c (though any advice is welcome) but when I run the script in 12c the first record is correct but all the following records have the same data and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

```
drop table temp purge;
create table temp (A CHAR(1), S1 varchar(32), S2 varchar(32));
commit;

insert into temp (A,S1)
select 'A', '1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4' from dual;
commit;
insert into temp (A,s1)
select 'B', '6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9' from dual;
commit;
insert into temp (A,s1)
select 'C', 'A B C D A B C D' from dual;
commit;

select * from temp;

UPDATE temp set (S2) = (
    SELECT LISTAGG(str, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) str
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(S1, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS str FROM dual
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(S1, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    )
);


select * from temp;
```

output:

```
A S1                               S2
- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
A 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
B 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9
C A B C D A B C D


3 rows updated.


A S1                               S2
- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
A 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4          1 2 3 4
B 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9  1 2 3 4
C A B C D A B C D                  1 2 3 4
```

expected:

```
A S1                               S2
- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
A 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4          1 2 3 4
B 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9  6 7 8 9
C A B C D A B C D                  A B C D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is, but here is an alternative solution that avoids the CPU penalty of using REGEXP:

```
update temp set s2 =
xmlcast(
  xmlquery(
    'string-join(distinct-values(tokenize($X, " ")), " ")'
    passing s1 as X returning content
  )
  as varchar2(64)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following, it should work -

```
update (
select temp.*
      ,(SELECT LISTAGG(str, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) str
          FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(S1, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS str FROM dual
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(S1, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
               )
        ) result
  from temp
)
set S2 = result
```

The key here is to make sure S2 is calculated for each row.